# battery terminal setup question

Tags: battery

Where is the proper place for cables with this type of connector?

[image]

I have my wires (the ones with end-connectors) between the bolt and metal plate, like such:

[image]

Should they be below the plate instead? I figured the metal plate is a good conductor, but I've seen people mount below this plate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll have much of an issue either way, though I think you'd have better off with a set like these than the ones you chose:

[image: Picture from Amazon.com]

To properly use the ones you purchased, normally you'd clip off the connectors at the end of the wires, then bare the wires (remove the insulation) about a 1/2" back, then put the bare wires under the clamp, holding them there until you get the clamps (metal part where you are attaching the wires at now, not the part which holds the battery terminal) snugged down.

Either way, if you coat the terminal area and clamps (all exposed metal) in a thin layer of grease, you'll find you won't have as much corrosion buildup over time.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case that makes not a big difference. Anyway there is a point on amperage. Then higher the amperage is, then more surface you need. When you do it over the plate, you surface is the bolt and the metal plate, that transfer a part on ampere over the plate to another bolt and then to connector. Under the plate it is the same, until you do not rub off the color under the plate. So your surface increase to bolt, plate and connector itself. Good is, if you scratch off the color under the plate and screw your wire also under the plate (more surface).